# Finding $k+1$ integers (duplicates allowed) on the interval $[0,n-2]$ whose sum is a constant.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $\mathbf \alpha=(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)\in \mathbb Z_{\ge 0}$ be such that for $n>k>1$:

1. $0\le \alpha_i\le n-2$,
2. $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i=n\cdot (k-1)$, and
3. $|i:\alpha_i\neq 0|=k+1$

How many of such vectors $\mathbf \alpha$ exist?

I'm not good at combinatorics but this is what I have tried so far: There are $k+1$ entries that are positive in any such vector. There are $n(n-1)\ldots(n-k)/(k+1)!$ possible ways of having $k+1$ positive entries. Is that correct?

For simplicity, let's assume that only the first $k+1$ entries are positive. I'm having a hard time trying to figure out in how many ways can we have have $0<\alpha_i\le n-2$ for $i=1,\ldots, k+1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} \alpha_i=n(k-1)$. If we removed the restriction that $\alpha_i\le n-2$ then the number of $(k+1)$-tuples whith positive integer entries that add up to $n(k-1)$ is $\binom{n(k-1)-1}{k}$ accordingly to this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_one).

Comment: Should your last $0<\alpha_i<n-2$ have $\alpha_i \le n-2$ like earlier?  Which is correct?  For the number of ways to select the nonzero positions, you want ${n \choose k+1}=\frac {n!}{(k+1)!(n-k-1)!}$ This matches your expression.  Now that you have chosen the nonzero ones, if they were all $1$s, they would add to $k+1$.  You need to distribute the remaining $n(k-1)-(k+1)=(n-1)k-2$ among the nonzero positions so that no position gets more than $n-3$

Comment: @RossMillikan: Thanks, I fixed the typo in my attempt. But, all of the first $k+1$ can not be equal to one since we assumed that only the first $k+1$ are positive, the others are zero.

Comment: Yes, you are looking for the number of compositions of $n(k-1)$ into $k+1$ parts that are at most $n-2$ or $n-3$.  Since all the parts have to be at least $1$, I am suggesting you start with each one being $1$ and distribute the rest.  This means you are looking for weak compositions of $(n-1)k-2$ into $k+1$ parts that are at most $n-3$ or $n-4$.  I don't have a solution or I would have answered.